# Merging CoreData SQL files

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I've been wrestling with this problem with quite some time now and still have yet to figure out the most efficient way of dealing with it.  Here are the details:

I have an app that uses Core Data to store the content for the app to show.  The app downloads the content in the form of a SQLite database and attempts to merge it with it's local version.  This is necessary because the downloaded content is often needs to be combined with content that the user downloaded prior.

To make things more complicated, on my end I also need a way of combining these files so their clean to download (in other words no extraneous relations or isolated objects in the core data file).  I have already built the editor for this, but again I run into the problem of merging these sqlite files.

I'd like to find a better way of combining these sqlite databases if that even exists.  I've seen that you can add many different store files using a persistent store coordinator, but coordinating all of the correct stores into a single download package becomes more difficult and dangerous.

The question is: what is the best way to use multiple sql stores and either make them into one convenient .sqlite file or have them operate seamlessly?

Answer (score 1):

First, don't think of this as an SQLite problem. It is a Core Data problem. If you use Core Data and SQLite in the same paragraph, you have already lost. CD does (sometimes) use SQLite as its backing store, but that knowledge doesn't help you solve this problem.

When I have had to solve the problem of combining static and user-generated data, I have usually used two different data models, with a unique ID on the static side under my control. Any combined references between static and live data I handle programmatically, which has worked fine because the user data is tiny compared to my static data.

You might also investigate fetched properties, which allow you to obtain values from a different persistent store.

I think merging your original static data with updated static data is the wrong way to go. That sort of operation will take a long time on the device.

Can you use three different persistent stores? The first would be bundled with your application, available immediately. The second would be updated data, downloaded from a server, and would be a complete replacement for the first. Finally you'd have a userdata store, connected to master data either with fetched properties or your roll-your-own unique ID.

It's also possible that Core Data is the wrong hammer for this particular nail. If you have a lot of SQLite expertise, and if you really are more comfortable working with SQLite than with Core Data, just skip Core Data. Do the entire thing in direct SQLite.